# Where is the best place to learn server administration for a CentOS WHM/cPanel sever?

Tags: centos, cpanel, whm, server-administration

I'd like to be able to manage my dedicated server properly. It's running WHM 11.28.87 and CENTOS 5.5 x86_64.

I can find my way around WHM and cPanel easy enough. I would really like to know the command line stuff/Common tasks/Best practices etc.

Video tutorials are preferred but I really just want the best resources.

Comment: I'd probably start with an [install guide](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/). Keep in mind that most commands and configuration files have documentation on the system: `man man` for details, `man ssh` for something immediately useful to know more about. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to learn the command line first, and then ideally specialise in stuff related to WHM and cPanel.

For a good starter on the command line try a Peepcode screencast like this one:

http://peepcode.com/products/meet-the-command-line